# Function to obtain BluetoothNameId from an identifier

Tags: kotlin

I have a class which is looking like this:

```
object IdentifierExtensions {

fun Identifier.toBluetoothNameId(): Identifier.BluetoothNameId? {

    val id = this.mId

    if (this is ControllerIdentifier.Id) {
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.containsKey(id)) {
            return IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache[id]
        }
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
            val fromControllerId = BluetoothIdControllerCreator.createFromControllerId(id)
            IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.put(id, fromControllerId)
            return fromControllerId
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId) {
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToBluetoothCache.containsKey(id)) {
            return IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToBluetoothCache[id]
        }
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBarcodeId(id)) {
            val fromBarcodeID = BluetoothIdControllerCreator.createFromBarcodeID(id)
            IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToBluetoothCache.put(id, fromBarcodeID)
            return fromBarcodeID
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")

    return this as Identifier.BluetoothNameId
}

fun Identifier.toIdController(): Identifier.ControllerId? {

    val id = this.mId

    if (this is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId) {
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToSerialCache.containsKey(id)) {
            return IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToSerialCache[id]
        }
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBarcodeId(id)) {
            val fromBarcodeID = IdControllerCreator.createFromBarcodeID(id)
            IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToSerialCache.put(id, fromBarcodeID)
            return fromBarcodeID
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothNameId) {
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromBluetoothToSerialCache.containsKey(id)) {
            return IdentifierManager.mFromBluetoothToSerialCache[id]
        }
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBluetoohId(id)) {
            val fromBluetoothID = IdControllerCreator.createFromBluetoothID(id)
            IdentifierManager.mFromBluetoothToSerialCache.put(id, fromBluetoothID)
            return fromBluetoothID
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")

    return this as Identifier.ControllerId
}

fun Identifier.toBarcodeIdController(): Identifier.FullSerialNumberId? {

    val id = this.mId

    if (this is Identifier.ControllerId) {
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBarcodeCache.containsKey(id)) {
            return IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBarcodeCache[id]
        }
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
            val fromControllerId = BarcodeIdControllerCreator.createFromControllerId(id)
            IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBarcodeCache.put(id, fromControllerId)
            return fromControllerId
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }
    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothNameId) {
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromBluetoothToBarcodeCache.containsKey(id)) {
            return IdentifierManager.mFromBluetoothToBarcodeCache[id]
        }
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBluetoohId(id)) {
            val fromBluetoothID = BarcodeIdControllerCreator.createFromBluetoothID(id)
            IdentifierManager.mFromBluetoothToBarcodeCache.put(id, fromBluetoothID)
            return fromBluetoothID
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")

    return this as Identifier.FullSerialNumberId
}

fun Identifier.canConvertToBluetoothNameId(): Boolean {
    val id = this.mId

    if (this is Identifier.ControllerId) {
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId) {
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBarcodeId(id)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

fun Identifier.canConvertToFullSerialNumberId(): Boolean {
    val id = this.mId

    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothNameId) {
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBluetoohId(id)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.ControllerId) {
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

fun Identifier.canConvertToId(): Boolean {
    val id = this.mId

    if (this is Identifier.BluetoothNameId) {
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBluetoohId(id)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    if (this is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId) {
        if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBarcodeId(id)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
 }
}
```

Is there a way to make the code more readable? I am from Java background and in the beginning of dig into Kotlin.

Can anyone provide propose ideas of how to make this code shorter and/or more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

I see two main readability issues here, one is only for Kotlin, but the other one should be a Java thing two.

If we take a look at your code snippet we can see that all functions are very similar, that means that I will just explain my concept on one of your functions, i.e. the first one, in this case `Identifier.toBluetoothNameId()`.

Also I will only go about readability and not functionality of your code since I first of all do not know what you are exactly working with and you also only asked for that.

In your function you have three base if-statements

```
if (this is ControllerIdentifier.Id) { 
    ... 
}
if (this is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId) { 
    ... 
}
if (this is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId)
    ...
```

In Kotlin you would approach this with a when-statement

```
when (this) {
    is ControllerIdentifier.Id -> { 
        ... 
    }
    is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId -> { 
        ... 
    }
    is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId -> ...
}
```

Additionally `when` can also be used as an expression in Kotlin, which would change the complete thing from

```
if (this is ControllerIdentifier.Id) { 
    ... 
    return Identifier.BluetoothNameId
}
if (this is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId) { 
    ... 
    return Identifier.BluetoothNameId
}
if (this is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId)
    return ...Identifier.BluetoothNameId
return this as Identifier.BluetoothNameId
```

to

```
return when (this) {
    is ControllerIdentifier.Id -> { 
        ... 
        Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    }
    is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId -> { 
        ... 
        Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    }
    is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId -> ...Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    else -> this as Identifier.BluetoothNameId
}
```

Note that in the when-expression with `return` in front, the return is left out in the blocks inside the `when` and the last value in a block will always be returned. You can read more about statements as expressions in Kotlin [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html).

Now your whole function looks like this

```
fun Identifier.toBluetoothNameId(): Identifier.BluetoothNameId? {
    val id = this.mId

    return when (this) {
        is ControllerIdentifier.Id -> { 
            ... 
            Identifier.BluetoothNameId
        }
        is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId -> { 
            ... 
            Identifier.BluetoothNameId
        }
        is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId -> ...Identifier.BluetoothNameId
        else -> this as Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    }
}
```

But this is not optimal. If you just sacrifice your shorting of `val id = this.mId` and write `this.mId` every time in your calls we can use this nice shortcut

```
fun Identifier.toBluetoothNameId() = when (this) {
    is ControllerIdentifier.Id -> { 
        ... 
        Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    }
    is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId -> { 
        ... 
        Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    }
    is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId -> ...Identifier.BluetoothNameId
    else -> this as Identifier.BluetoothNameId
}
```

Because we are now using an [expression body](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-functions) we can even omit the return type because Kotlin automatically detects it.

The second thing I would change in your code is using two if-statements in a row, instead of `if else`. This is something that I would also prefer in Java when there is no need for two separate if-statements. It simply saves a line and shows the reader that the two statements check the same thing.

Instead of

```
if (IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.containsKey(id)) {
        return IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache[id]
}
if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
    val fromControllerId = BluetoothIdControllerCreator.createFromControllerId(id)
    IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.put(id, fromControllerId)
    return fromControllerId
}
```

I would do this

```
if (IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.containsKey(id)) {
        return IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache[id]
} else if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
    val fromControllerId = BluetoothIdControllerCreator.createFromControllerId(id)
    IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.put(id, fromControllerId)
    return fromControllerId
}
```

Before I just left out your code with "...", now I will insert it to make clear what I am talking about completely. So the function `Identifier.toBluetoothNameId()` now looks like this

```
fun Identifier.toBluetoothNameId() = when (this) {
    is ControllerIdentifier.Id -> { 
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.containsKey(this.mId)) {
            IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache[id]
        } else if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerId(id)) {
            val fromControllerId = BluetoothIdControllerCreator.createFromControllerId(this.mId)
            IdentifierManager.mFromSerialToBluetoothCache.put(this.mId, fromControllerId)
            fromControllerId
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }
    is Identifier.FullSerialNumberId -> { 
        if (IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToBluetoothCache.containsKey(this.mId)) {
            IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToBluetoothCache[id]
        } else if (ControllerParser.parseValidControllerBarcodeId(this.mId)) {
            val fromBarcodeID = BluetoothIdControllerCreator.createFromBarcodeID(this.mId)
            IdentifierManager.mFromBarcodeToBluetoothCache.put(this.mId, fromBarcodeID)
            fromBarcodeID
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
        }
    }
    is Identifier.BluetoothBrickedId -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid convertion")
    else -> this as Identifier.BluetoothNameId
}
```

Okay, I think you should be able to apply this to your other functions by yourself now.

Concerning functionality I would say that you could see if there is a possibility to shorten those three long very similar functions to one long and three rather short ones, but I did not find a solution in a hurry right here.

**Side note**: I think you misspelled "conver**s**ion" ^^

*Thank you for reading :)*